# Triangulation of Lattice Polygons

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory, recreational-mathematics

What's a neat proof that every lattice polygon can be split into elementary triangles?

By a lattice polygon I mean a polygon with vertices on some equidistant grid; by an elementary triangle I mean a lattice polygon on three vertices with no other boundary or interior points.

Answer (score 4):

We choose a graph $G$ with $v$ vertices and construct a $v$-vertex polygon either via triangulating it or erasing edges from a maximally planar graph of $n$-vertices. We then turn triangular regions into triangles through [Fáry's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/F%C3%A1ry%27s_theorem).

**1)** Let $G$ be the graph of a lattice polygon. The vertices $G$ form a closed path. Choose a face inside the closed path: if it is not triangular, then draw an edge between two unconnected vertices, if it is triangular, leave it alone. Repeat the process until all bounded regions of $G$ are triangular. We can't draw any more edges since a triangular region is formed by $K_{3}$.

A closed path bounding a nontriangular face never has edges between non-adjacent vertices, so we should always be able to draw one without making $G$ nonplanar.

**2)** We know that in a simple planar graph $e \leq 3v - 6$, so the maximum $e$ is $3v - 6$. This is possible only when $2e = 3f$ (this is the inequality from which the first one is derived, namely $3f \leq 2e$). If a face $f$ is triangular, then $3f$ is the same as counting every edge bounding it twice. So, to count every edge in the graph twice using faces, each must be part of a triangular region.

We showed that a maximal planar graph with $v$ vertices can be triangulated with $3v - 6$ edges. Erase edges until only the desired polygon remains, which is composed of triangular regions.

The planar graphs constructed through **(1)** and **(2)** can be drawn with straight line segments by [Fáry's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/F%C3%A1ry%27s_theorem), turning the triangular regions into actual triangles.

Comment: Nice play of a name on Sonic Hedgehog